# MySQL: Count continuous months

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to count the occurrences when a user perform something in consecutive months. Ex.

```
| Person     | Datetime              | 
| person_01  | '2015-01-02 10:40:15' | 
| person_01  | '2015-02-02 10:40:15' | 
| person_01  | '2015-07-05 10:40:15' | 
| person_02  | '2015-01-02 10:40:15' | 
| person_02  | '2015-04-03 10:40:15' | 
| person_02  | '2015-07-09 10:40:15' |
```

Result:

```
| Created    |  Consecutive  |
| person_01  |  1            |
| person_02  |  0            |
```

(I was trying to start by group by year(datetime), month(datetime), but would like to see some examples of solutions for this if possible.)

Any recommendations or examples to help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by combination of rownumber generation and `timestampdiff`

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87c20/9)

```
SET @row_number1:=0; 

SET @row_number2:=0; 

SELECT T1.person, 
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,T1.ddatetime,T2.ddatetime)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CNT CNT 
FROM   (SELECT @row_number1 := @row_number1 + 1 AS row_number, 
               person, 
               ddatetime 
        FROM   datedata 
        ORDER  BY person, 
                  ddatetime) T1 
       INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT @row_number2 := @row_number2 + 1 AS row_number, 
                          person, 
                          ddatetime 
                   FROM   datedata 
                   ORDER  BY person, 
                             ddatetime) T2 
               ON T1.row_number + 1 = T2.row_number 
                  AND T1.person = T2.person 
GROUP  BY T1.person
```

Comment: This looks good, but I made a test with different hours and it returns no records. I think maybe I didn't explained well. It should check only the month, it doesn't matte the time or day, just check if something happen in 2 or more continuous months (if 3 months in sequence, show 3...) Thank you.

Comment: @IgorO : I updated answer and Fiddle. That should work as you desired.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do something like this:

```
select base.person, count(subq.dt) consequtive
-- get distinct person
from (select distinct person from test) base
-- join with a subquery
left join

(
  select a.* 
  from 
    -- convert date to first day of the month
    (select person, 
      cast(concat(left(dt,7), '-01') as date) as dt 
    from test) a 

  join 

    -- convert date to first day of the month
    -- and subtract a month
    (select person, 
       date_sub(cast(concat(left(dt,7), '-01') as  date), interval 1 month) as dt 
     from test) b 

  -- join the above 2 by person and date
  on a.person = b.person and a.dt = b.dt
) subq

on subq.person = base.person
group by base.person;

Result:
| person | consequtive |
|--------|-------------|
|     01 |           1 |
|     02 |           0 |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1fed/6

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table is called table (unlikely I know)

Something like this would list them all

```
select A.Person from table A join table B on A.Person = B.Person
where A.Datetime = date_add(B.Datetime, interval 1 day) order by A.Datetime
```

And something like this should sum them up

```
select A.Person, count (A.Person) from table A join table B on A.Person = B.Person
where A.Datetime = date_add(B.Datetime, interval 1 day) group by A.Person
```

I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

This the logic you have to use. I tried it in `oracle` but the logic should work in mysql too. You just have to find corresponding functions.

1. Find a way to remove the date and timestamp part from your date. So it should have just month and year (like 201501). Call it curr_month.
2. Create another temporary table and add another column by adding 1 month to your new month_year. Call it next_month
3. Now do a self join on this temp table on `id` and `curr_month=next_month`
4. This will give you the ids which are there in consecutive months. Do a group by id and count(*) to get your result.

   ```
               with tbl (id ,Month_year) as
               (select 1,'20150101' from dual union
                select 1,'20150201' from dual union
                 select 1,'20150701' from dual union
                select 2,'20150101' from dual union
                 select 2,'2015041' from dual union
                select 2,'20150701' from dual
                ),tbl2 as(
                select tbl.*, to_date(Month_year,'YYYYMMDD') as curr_month, add_months( to_date(Month_year,'YYYYMMDD'),1) as next_month from tbl order by id,curr_month)
                ,tbl3 as(
                select t1.id from tbl2 t1 inner join
                tbl2 t2 on
                t1.id=t2.id
                and t1.curr_month=t2.next_month)
                select distinct id as created,count(*) as consecutive from tbl3 group by id
   ```